# Python permutation using recursion

Tags: python, permutation

I am using Python, and I want to generate all the permutations of a list while considering the following constraint:

- **Every** permutation starts with the number 0

Thus, I have the following list `li = [1,2,3,4]`, and I am interested in finding all the permutations for these 4 numbers while adding the number 0 at index 0 to each of the permutations.

For example:

`[0,1,2,3,4]`

`[0,1,3,2,4]`

and so on.

I would especially appreciate answers that do not rely on `itertools`.

Comment: So you want to add to the permutation the 0 in the front?

Comment: Show some results your algorithm should produce. Add them to your question via [Edit].

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do, and what specific issue you need help with. Also consider to reword the description of your task – *no* permutation of 1,2,3,4 starts with 0.

Comment: I edited my answer, and I hope that it is more clear now what I am trying to achieve. I want to do exactly what Dani Mesejo mentioned.

Comment: Why don't you want to use itertools?  This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: This still seems very much like a task description, and very little like an actual question. There are tons of published code for creating permutations, including ``itertools`` cited in the question. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, but Q&A as outlined in the [ask] help pages. What are you *asking*? What specific *problem* do you need help with? *Why* do you reject ``itertools``, and does this apply to other approaches as well?

Comment: I did not want to use ```itertools```, as I have already found a solution using it. I am trying to understand the logic behind solutions which did not use ```itertools``` but recursive functions, thus my question. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution which takes into account the constraint which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def create_perm(actual_list, add_list):
    """
    Recursive function for the creation of the permutation
    """
    if len(add_list)==1:
        # If you reach the last item, print the found permutation
        # (add the 0 at the beginning)
        print([0] + actual_list + add_list)
    else:
        for i in add_list:
            # Go one step deeper by removing one item and add it to the found permutation
            new_add_list = add_list.copy()
            new_add_list.remove(i)
            # Make the recursion
            create_perm(actual_list + [i], new_add_list)
    
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
create_perm([], li)
```